# Why does my Android Test crash when calling JNI callback?

Tags: android, multithreading, junit, java-native-interface

I'm wrapping up a C++ library to use in my Android project. The library has several asynchronous functions which needs a couple of work on JNI layer. Basically, I'm expecting an `IThreadRunner` in the C++ side in order to create any background thread my lib needs. I have a subclass for the JNI that will attach and detach the created thread, in order to allow callbacks. Everything is working as a charm in a normal Android App. However, I'm getting **JNI error (crash) in the java callbacks from JNI** when calling the async code from androidTest.

```
2019-08-22 09:10:44.785 11897-11897/---.-----.------ A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: thread Thread[1,tid=11897,Native,Thread*=0xabd8b400,peer=0x754d6000,"main"] using JNIEnv* from thread Thread[1,tid=11897,Native,Thread*=0xabd8b400,peer=0x754d6000,"main"]
```

I've been through these errors before when I was not attaching the callback thread to JNI. This is not the case now. If you have a double check in this error message, it says thread X is trying to use JNIEnv* from thread X, which is completely acceptable and should not be and error.

Note this only happens when running an instrumented test (androidTest). I know the test runs in its own thread, but I'm using `runBlocking(Dispatchers.Main) {` to have the same behaviour I see in a normal Android App.

This is part of the body of my test file

```
package ---.-----.------

import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4
import android.util.Log
import ---.-----.------.-----------
import ---.-----.------.------
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking
import org.junit.Assert.assertEquals
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith

/**
 * Instrumented test, which will execute on an Android device.
 *
 * See [testing documentation](http://d.android.com/tools/testing).
 */
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class MyInstrumentedTest {
    @Test
    fun basicSocketTest() = runBlocking {
         ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is rather light on details. Does [extended JNI checking](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni#extended-checking) produce extra information?

Comment: I did try to disable CheckJNI but I always get `I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni`

Comment: Disabling CheckJNI is not the solution! I found [this commit](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/art/+/35e827a%5E%21/#F0) that should produce the correct error message. It was merged in Android 7 Nougat (I think), so which version are you testing on?

Comment: I'm using API 24 Android 7.0 Nougat (Google Play). But it also fails on my real device (Samsung Galaxy S8 on Android 9)

Comment: Regardless, this error message is only generated whether the `JNIEnv` you are using is attached to a different thread, so check your code for instances where you store or pass `JNIEnv` pointers around.

Comment: Why should this crash on instrumented test but not in a regular app?

Comment: At a guess: maybe several tests are run in different threads? Or maybe each test is run sequentially in a different thread?